# How I can send signal from android mobile through speaker?

Tags: audio

Would you please let me know how I can send signal from android mobile through speaker ?

Please let me know if you need more clarification .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you clarify what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: could it be serial port communication?